# React native calculate network usage (Android & iOS)

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-ios

I am currently developing a react native app integrating it with IPFS technology, I have an requirement to calculate network usage in my app, that is how much data is used while sending and receiving the information from IPFS.

I have searched for plugins, but was only able to get it for Android.

So, what I have thought is to get size of Bytes sent and received from my app and to calculate data usage based on it.. is this a correct approach to get the network usage stats of my app ?

If there is any another way available for both Android & iOS platforms (hopefully plugin as I am not an Native developer) then please suggest.

Thanks.